# What jQuery Mobile event is best for

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am developing a jQuery Mobile application that will run into a Cordova wrapper.
I am struggling to understand the use of each pagecontainerX event and when to use which.
I will post three specific use cases:

1) hook click events:
Say I want to assign a handler to a certain click event on a button.

2) change textual content of the page:
Say I have a page and I want to update some content that might have changed since last time I have shown the page.

3) change graphical content of the page:
Like if I want to draw on some canvas, or in cases where I need to know how things are rendered and their size.

Answer (score 0):

#### Preliminary answers:

these is what I have found myself, but I would really much appreciate comments:

1) I am using the *pagecreate* event, as it's only called once. It is also possible to specify what specific page you want to hook the handler to by doing: $(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageid", handler);

2) I am using *pagecontainerbeforetransition* or *pagecontainerbeforehide*. Pagecontainerbeforehide has the advantage that is only fired once, while the other is fired twice (dunno why). Other options, like *pagecontainershow*, will change the content after transition, which is a bit weird to look at.

3) In this case I am employing *pagecontainershow*, so that things have already been graphically rendered and I can compute heights and widths etc., the drawback is that the user will see the transition, and only after he will see the content of the page being modified.